# Launcher Icon not working even after getting "✓ Successfully generated launcher icons"

Tags: android, flutter, launcher-icon

I am trying to add a launcher icon to my flutter app. I have followed all the steps required to create a launcher icon.

**This is my pubspec.yaml file**

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  image_path_android: "icons/opicon.png"



  image_path: icons/opicon.png
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
```

**I have even made a change in android/app/build.gradle file**

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.loginpage"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

**I have even got a successful message from flutter**

```
PS D:\Flutter_Projects\loginpage> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.9.1)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════

• Creating default icons Android
• Overwriting the default Android launcher icon with a new icon
• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
```

But on the emulator, the launcher icon hasn't changed. It still has the default flutter icon.

This is the screenshot of the emulator

[image]

**This is my project folder**

[image]

The Highlighted folder is where I am having the icon image.

Comment: Can you recheck your asset's path, and try removing command then again  create command.

Comment: Please try to remove 'image_path_android' option and change from 'image_path: icons/opicon.png' to 'image_path: "icons/opicon.png"'

Comment: And check whether again icon file exist in 'assets' folder. If that, change path to "assets/icons/opicon.png"

Comment: minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 30

Comment: change this and again run the command

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to change Launcher Icons,

Go to https://appicon.co/ and add your icon and generate it will give zip file, Extract this file and copy this folder and change in our project Android and Ios folder.

> android - LOGINPAGE/android/app/src/main/res
>
> ios - LOGINPAGE/ios/Runner

Then, add dependency

```
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
```

Add,

```
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "icons/opicon.png"
  remove_alpha_ios: true
```

run this command on terminal,

```
flutter pub get

flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Then, it's done!

Comment: I got 2 folders(Android, Assets.xcassets) and 2 images(playstore.png, appstore.png). Should I have all these in a single folder and then add it to "LOGINPAGE/android/app/src/main/res" or should I add only a particular file to "LOGINPAGE/android/app/src/main/res"

Comment: First open the **Android** folder and copy all this folder insides it and replace in _LOGINPAGE/android/app/src/main/res_ & then copy Assets.xcassets and replace in _LOGINPAGE/ios/Runner_. Then follow next steps!

Comment: Got it, Sir. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

In pubspec.yaml file-

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

and then run

flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

After creating icon successful, uninstall app and then flutter run.